# Why i keep getting an error to install .net even i have it installed inside my windows 10 PC

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, windows-10

I want to install a program which requires .net to be installed. now inside my Windows 10 i installed the .net 6.0 both the runtime and the SDK, but when i try to install the progrma i keep getting this error:-

```
To install this application you must install .NET
```

[image]

Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: Simple googling gives reference to [https://github.com/arkane-systems/mousejiggler#readme](https://github.com/arkane-systems/mousejiggler#readme) and the instruction says that the **.NET 5** should be installed. Anyway the error dialog contains the **Yes** button to continue installation of the required .NET version.

Comment: @Victor i followed the browser which open when click on Yes and it redirect me to version 6

Comment: @Victor can i have version 5 & 6 installed on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, actually .NET 6 is including the .NET 5. Therefore, I would recommend try to check the Windows Log in the Event Viewer for any errors that might be help to understand what the really error is. Perhaps the _Windows Log_ contains some more detailed information about the problem. If no error is found in the Event Viewer add a new bug to the [https://github.com/arkane-systems/mousejiggler/issues](https://github.com/arkane-systems/mousejiggler/issues)

Comment: If possible, for testing purposes, you could remove/ uninstall the .NET SDK and runtime from the machine.  Restart the machine. While installing the program, click Yes to install the .NET and follow the process to install it, and see whether it helps you fix the issue. If possible, you could try to install any other recent version of the program to see whether it works.